# How to use both if and elif results on terminal

Tags: python

I made a program that reads 3 length segments and tells you if they can create a triangle, if so it prints you can.
But i also want it to additionally tell you that if all segments are equal, you can create a equilateral triangle.
The problem is that the code stops when the first if gets attended.
I don't know how to implement what i want.

My code:

```
r1 = int(input('Determine a length: '))
r2 = int(input('Determine another length: '))
r3 = int(input('Determine one more length: '))
if (r1+r2) > r3 and (r2+r3) > r1 and (r1+r3) > r2:
    print('You can form a triangule.')
elif r1 == r2 == r3:
    print("You can form a equilateral triangle.")
else:
    print("You can't form a triangle.")
```

Comment: indent the second condition and change it from elif to if

Comment: Hint: the equilateral triangle case is a special case of the more general triangle case. Once you determine the general case is true, you should then test whether the special case is true. At present, your code says an equilateral triangle only exists when a triangle of any kind doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indent the second condition and change it from `elif` to `if` so it will get checked if the first condition is met:

```
r1 = int(input('Determine a length: '))
r2 = int(input('Determine another length: '))
r3 = int(input('Determine one more length: '))
if (r1+r2) > r3 and (r2+r3) > r1 and (r1+r3) > r2:
    print('You can form a triangule.')
    if r1 == r2 == r3:
        print("You can form a equilateral triangle.")
else:
    print("You can't form a triangle.")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Didn't know that you could do a "if" inside of another "if". Really helpful!